# Android Studio only save changes by clicking "Run" twice

Tags: android

My android studio does not save changes after clicking "Run App".
it does after running the app twice!
Can Anyone help?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue.
I fixed it by disabling the hot-swap agent for Groovy code.

You can do so by going to Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Debugger -> HotSwap and then remove the checkmark at `Enable hot-swap agent for Groovy code`

For sure not the best solution, but always running the app twice is also quite annoying...

Comment: Although the app is updated much more reliable now, it still sometimes needs two runs for the changes to be applied...

Comment: Seems to be fixed in version 4.2

Comment: Yes , it is fixed now after updating to a newer version. Thank you